# Opening 2 serial ports simultaneously in python (one tx one for rx)

Tags: python, pyserial

I am making a throughput test for a bluetooth link, and I need to send data through a serial port to one bluetooth device which will then transport that data wirelessly to another bluetooth device.  The other device will then complete the circuit by sending the data back to the host PC via a different serial port.

The problem seems to be when I attempt to open up 2 different instances of PySerial, the program simply hangs.  I have isolated it down to running vs. hanging when I comment out one of the two serial port instantiations.  Anyone see a problem with how I'm doing this?  If so, what is the proper way to do this? See code below:

```
#/usr/bin/python

import serial
import time
import sys

DEFAULT_BAUD = 115200
SEND_SIZE = 100

def addPath(file):
    pth, fl = os.path.split(__file__)
    return os.path.join(pth, file)

def is_number(s):
    try:
        int(s, 16)
        return True
    except:
        return False

class SerialReader():
    def __init__(self, portRx, portTx):
        self.portTx = portTx
        self.portRx = portRx
        self.start_time__sec = time.time()
        self.interval__sec = 0
        self.buffer = []
        self.sendtext = ''.join([str(i) for i in range(SEND_SIZE)])

    # send first batch of data
    self.portTx.write(self.sendtext)

    def didDataArrive(self):

        # Read port
        self.buffer.extend(list(self.portRx.read(1024)))

        # Step through the buffer byte and byte and see if the tick text
        # is at the front.
        while len(self.buffer) >= len(self.sendtext):
            if self.buffer[:len(self.sendtext)] == self.sendtext:

                # Discard the tick text
                self.buffer = self.buffer[len(self.sendtext):]

                # Record time
                snapshot__sec = time.time()
                self.interval__sec = snapshot__sec - self.start_time__sec
                self.start_time__sec = snapshot__sec
                # send more data
                self.portTx.write(self.sendtext)
                return True

            else:
                self.buffer.pop(0)

        return False

def main(port1, port2, baudrate1 = DEFAULT_BAUD, baudrate2 = DEFAULT_BAUD):
    try:
        import serial
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print "="*60
        print "You need to install PySerial"
        print "Windows: easy_install pyserial"
        print "Mac/Linux: sudo easy_install pyserial"

    try:
        s1 = serial.Serial(port1, baudrate1, timeout = 0.1)
        s2 = serial.Serial(port2, baudrate2, timeout = 0.1)
        print "Loading serial ports"
    except:
        print "Serial port error"
        exit()

    plot_stop = False

    dataread = SerialReader(s2, s1)

    try:
        while plot_stop == False:
            if dataread.didDataArrive():
                print dataread.interval__sec

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Keyboard Interrupt"
        plot_stop = True

    finally:
        print "Closing"
        s1.close()
        s2.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if (len(sys.argv) < 3):
        print "Usage: python extract_data.py phonelink_serialport phonelinkclient_serialport [baudrate1] [baudrate2]"
    else:
        main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

If I remove one of the following lines (doesn't matter which one), the python script runs (although it eventually crashes because in the code it eventually tries to reference both ports).  If I leave these lines in, the program seems to just hang (it just seems to sit there and run indefinitely):

```
s1 = serial.Serial(port1, baudrate1, timeout = 0.1)
s2 = serial.Serial(port2, baudrate2, timeout = 0.1)
```

Comment: Where exactly does the program hang? So we can narrow down on the problem, it'd help to know where it gets stuck.

Comment: @MichaelMulqueen: Done

Comment: *At which line* does it get stuck?  You said "If I remove one of the following lines...the python script runs", but is it getting stuck *on one of those lines* or somewhere following that in the code?  `print` is your friend.

Comment: It doesn't matter which one is removed.  If both are there the print after it does not get called and if only one (either of them) is present the print immediately after shows up